# Serving http data from two servers

Tags: virtualhost, apache-2.4

I have an Ubuntu server behind a NAT router / firewall. I would like to add another server, serving content from both servers over http(s). As I understand it I can have the "main" server request data from another IP depending on which vhost is being called.

However I need to understand how that is done and which kind of setup is needed. Is the data being routed through the "main" server or is the data served directly from server 2? Is there any other sharing needed to happen between servers like access to the files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The technology you are looking for is called `reverse proxying`. Typically you would have a (series of) vhost on the 'front end' machine that either return data directly or reverse proxy the request to a different machine. We have [lots of Q&A about that here on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/search?q=proxypass) and the wider internet has plenty of information too.